# Print on php page what runs on background (Terminal) php_exec

Tags: php, shell, terminal, exec, echo

I run a soft like ffmpeg with exec function. What I want is to see what is happening on the terminal the same time the command runs, I don't know if I can do it with echo or not. So, I need your help.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the output of a command *before* it has finished, you should use a combination of popen() and flush(). There is a good example in the php.net docs, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php#56604